# In John 9:10 why didn't the blind man make the connection between his healing,Jesus and Son of Man?

Tags: john, christology, gospels, miracle

John 9:10

> So they said to him, “Then how were your eyes opened?” 11 He answered, “The man called Jesus made mud and anointed my eyes and said to me, ‘Go to Siloam and wash.’ So I went and washed and received my sight.”

After having been healed by Jesus somehow the blind man seems to know who had healed him but somehow does not make any connection between his healing,Jesus and the Son of Man, but he clearly understood that a man sent from God was able to heal the blind

John 9:31 ESV

> We know that God does not listen to sinners, but if anyone is a worshiper of God and does his will, God listens to him. 32 Never since the world began has it been heard that anyone opened the eyes of a man born blind.

Later when he meets Jesus again and he is introduced to the Son of Man again he professes ignorance concerning the Son of Man

John 9:35

> Jesus heard that they had cast him out, and having found him he said, ***“Do you believe in the Son of Man?”[c] 36 He answered, “And who is he, sir, that I may believe in him?” 37 Jesus said to him, “You have seen him, and it is he who is speaking to you.”***

Why didn't the blind man make the connection between his healing,Jesus and the Son of Man?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This man born blind never actually saw the one curing his blindness, Jesus. Sight was not restored to him until after he'd carried out Jesus' instruction, to go to the Pool of Siloam to wash off the mud Jesus had placed over his eyes. By the time he'd done that, at which point he saw for the first time in his life, Jesus was no longer around. The man went home.

Later, his astonished neighbours asked how his eyes were opened. He said that the man called Jesus had done it, but he apparently did not know anything about Jesus. When the religious leaders interrogated him about the miracle, the poor man could only keep repeating the couple of sentences he'd been saying all along. When it was then demanded of him, "What do you have to say about him?" he made a logical deduction - "He is a prophet... If this man were not from God, he could do nothing".

Later, Jesus had heard that the man had been thrown out by the Pharisees, and Jesus sought him out. Bear in mind that the man had never had sight of Jesus, which accounts for the events of John 9:35-41. Jesus raised the matter of who the Son of Man is, asking if he believed in him. "Sir, who is he, that I may believe in him" the man asked. When Jesus identified himself as that one, who had restored his sight, then the man instantly made the connection you ask about.

It was impossible for him to link Jesus with the Son of Man until Jesus revealed this to him. Once the man could see this Jesus, who had given him sight, and had been told by Jesus himself that he was this Son of Man, belief came instantly. After all, this Jesus had miraculously cured his blindness and, as he'd said to the Pharisees, "If this man were not from God, he could do nothing." But Jesus' self-identification, to his face, proved that this Jesus was more than a prophet - he was the very Son of Man, foretold to appear as the Messiah.